# Using Ajax Slider control dynamically?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Ajax slider control in which if the user types numbers into the input element the slider moves appropriately.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <br />    
    <asp:TextBox ID="Slider2_BoundControl" runat="server" Width="30" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Slider2" runat="server" />
    <br />
   <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender2" runat="server"
        BehaviorID="Slider2"
        TargetControlID="Slider2"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="100"
        BoundControlID="Slider2_BoundControl"
        Steps="5" />
```

But what i need is i want the slider to be in the middle whatever value i enter in the text box for the first time and then if i move the slider rightside means my value in the textbox has to increase and for leftside it has to decrease without setting these minimum and maximum values..

Example: what i need is when i enter 500 in the textbox my slider has to move to the center automatically..if i move the slider rightside the end must be 1000 and for leftside it must be 0 and if i enter 400 slider must move to center position automatically and the rightside end must be 800 and leftside 0.

Exactly like this in the fiddle 
here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cXYC4/

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hello, found any solution? Having the same problem here...